# Why SQL can't infer tables dependencies when dropping multiple tables with constraints?

Tags: sql, rdbms

Greetings,

It's a general SQL question not tied to any specific implementation but more on global concepts.

Let's take a simple example, I have 2 tables:

- User (with FK on Group)
- Group

Why when doing `DROP TABLE group, user;` the server can't infer tables dependency and reorder table names internally to do a successful drop ?

What is the purpose of making it fail ?

- Because developer are already so lazy, and they need some dependencies challenges during their time...
- Because no SQL database developer had this idea before...

Or without sarcasm:

- By design... bad design
- For security purpose... but don't see what security breach this 'feature' is helpful for ?
- Or it's simply a misunderstanding of SQL concept from my part

Would love to understand, thanks you !

Comment: What do you mean with “reorder table names”? If you drop them they should not be renamed but dropped, right?

Comment: @Kissaki I don't see your point I don't want to *rename* but I want table name to be *reordered* internally to do a successful drop on multiple tables with constrain... have you read correctly ?

Comment: Just a thought, but I wonder if the old bug having to do with naming a table "group" (a reserved word) has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some RDBMSes, [like PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/ddl-depend.html), you can use the `CASCADE` keyword to drop dependencies as well.

Comment: Good to know ! but I'm more interested about the design of the spec instead of specific vendor tricks.

Comment: Oh...I thought it was part of the spec (although I couldn't say for sure) because of how the PostgreSQL docs say, "According to the SQL standard, specifying either RESTRICT or CASCADE is required."

Comment: @Kev not sure if it's in the spec, perhaps i spook too fast, gonna check now

Comment: @Alois: I could be mistaken but I think that cascading deletes *are* a part of the SQL standard, however it's designed such that you must state your desire for cascades explicitly. Maybe it was felt that implicit cascades could be too dangerous? Also, not all systems will implement it.

Comment: @Kev seems to be in SQL:2003 gonna some test and accept your answer if that's work as expected, thanks

Comment: Check here: http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt I think this is the SQL-92 standard.

Comment: That's sound good but unfortunately don't seems to work as expected on MySQL ... work only if order is correct. So the only advantage I see is to drop table that are not listed in the table names but that must be deleted due to constraints ... I think it can work by doing one DROP CASCADE statement by table.

Comment: It's true, it doesn't drop any unnamed tables for you, just constraints.  If you're looking to `DROP user` just by saying `DROP group CASCADE` you're right, this isn't part of things.  However, it wouldn't be too hard to whip up a script that would crawl FK dependencies and drop any associated tables for you, and perhaps someone already has.